# Sequelize: how to update with associations?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have this structure of Models, using Sequelize:

```
class Company extends Model {
    static init(sequelize) {
        super.init({
            name: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
            email: { type: DataTypes.STRING }
        }, {
            sequelize
        });
    }

    static associate(models) {
        this.HasMany(models.Address, { foreignKey: 'company_id', as: 'addresses' })
    }
}

class Address extends Model {
    static init(sequelize) {
        super.init({
            street: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
            zipcode: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
            city: { type: DataTypes.STRING }
        }, {
            sequelize
        });
    }

    static associate(models) {
        this.BelongsTo(models.Company, { foreignKey: 'company_id', as: 'company' })        
    }
}
```

I need "Company" and "Address" to be updated simultaneously in the database, when the API has a *put* request, sending a JSON file.

Insert worked simultaneously, with the code:

```
await Company.create(company,{
  include: [{
    association: 'addresses'
  }]
});
```

However, when using the update method, it only updates the data of "Company" but "Address" does not change.

Has anyone been through this and has a solution? I couldn't find anything in the Sequelize manual

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know how the associated-create option works, IRL.  As I know it, SQL doesn't have a way to insert into multiple tables at once.  So, my guess is there is some auto-magic going on.

WRT updating, you're stuck with a good ol' fashioned multi-step save/create/update process.  I don't know what your constraints are but look into the [associative setter](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/associations.html#associating-objects).  This is a destructive little bugger, so watch out.  But it can be especially useful if the user can update, add, or delete an Address on that PUT call.

Also, it may be worth it [putting this whole effort on one transaction](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/transactions.html).  This won't make the query less-expensive.  But if things go wrong, they rollback together.

Comment: I really need to use a only transaction.
I found something interesting, about using *Promise.all* to solve this problem ... If it works, I'll post the solution here. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With `@hatchifyjs/sequelize-create-with-associations` it is as simple as:

```
const company = await Company.create({
  name: 'Name',
  email: 'email@email.com',
  addresses: [
    {
      street: 'Street',
      zipcode: '12345',
      city: 'City'
    }
  ]
});

await Company.update({
  name: 'Updated',
  addresses: [
    {
      street: 'New Street',
      zipcode: '54321',
      city: 'New City'
    }
  ]
}, { where: { id: company.id } });
```